# How to map key combination to output unicode symbol in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to create a keyboarding binding in Intellij (MacOS) to map the combination of `Option+'` to the Unicode character `ʹ` (U+0374).

I've tried to configure MacOS `DefaultKeyBinding.dict` with:

```
"~'" = ("insertText:", "ʹ");
```

and it works everywhere, except for IntelliJ.

How can I achieve that with IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible now because of this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127470